# Unable to setup Apache NiFi behind AWS ALB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-alb

I am having an issue setting up Apache NiFi behind AWS ALB. I can currently access the UI when hitting the server's public IP address directly but have been unsuccessful getting it working behind the ALB. It does work behind the ALB when HTTPS is not setup in NiFi. It fails to work when NiFi https is enabled with certificate authentication. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

1 Enable another authentication NIFI (ldap or openID)
2 Create a target group in AWS
with next parameter
target group -- IP
protocol version HTTP1